# Why am I getting a blank frame with this Android OpenGL Framebuffer code?

Tags: android, opengl-es, bitmap, framebuffer

I'm trying to apply a framebuffer (with a renderbuffer) to a Surface that gets video frames directly from the Android camera. I'm capturing the frames and saving them to disk.

Here is the code:

```
  String filename = file.toString();

    int width = getWidth();
    int height = getHeight();
    ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(width * height * 4);
    buf.order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN);

    int[] fboId = new int[1];
    int[] rendId = new int[1];

   GLES20.glGenFramebuffers(1, fboId, 0);
  GLES20.glBindFramebuffer(GLES20.GL_FRAMEBUFFER, fboId[0]);

    GLES20.glGenRenderbuffers(1, rendId, 0);
    GLES20.glBindRenderbuffer(GLES20.GL_RENDERBUFFER, rendId[0]);
    GLES20.glRenderbufferStorage(GLES20.GL_RENDERBUFFER,GLES20.GL_RGBA4, width, height);


   GLES20.glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GLES20.GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GLES20.GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GLES20.GL_RENDERBUFFER,rendId[0] );


    GLES20.glViewport(0,0,width, height);
    Log.i(TAG, "Complete? "+ GLES20.GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE);

   GLES20.glReadPixels(0, 0, width, height,
            GLES20.GL_RGBA, GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, buf);


    GlUtil.checkGlError("glReadPixels");
    buf.rewind();

    BufferedOutputStream bos = null;
    try {
        Long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        bos = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(filename));
        Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

     bmp.copyPixelsFromBuffer(buf);
        bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, bos);
        bmp.recycle();
        Log.i("time elapsed", String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()-startTime) + " milliseconds");
    } finally {
        if (bos != null) bos.close();
    }
    Log.d(TAG, "Saved " + width + "x" + height + " frame as '" + filename + "'");
}
```

IMPORTANT NOTE: it's the framebuffer/renderbuffer implemntation that is at issue here. I know this because I had the code working without the framebuffer (remove everything from

```
int[] fboID
```

to

```
GLES20.glViewport
```

I inherited this code from Google Grafika and it works without the framebuffer. I'm adding the framebuffer so I can quickly rotate the image before saving it as a bitmap.
The question is: what am I doing wrong in my Framebuffer implementation that 
yields a blank frame at 3.6kb in size (even though the resolution is 1280x720).

I'm expecting this code to render a frame from my EGLSurfaceBase context, and save it to disk as a bitmap. If the code doesn't do that - what's missing? I can't see the difference between this and other tutorials on Framebuffers that I've been using as templates.

Comment: I don't quite understand what your expectation is. You never render anything. You only just create a framebuffer before calling `glReadPixels()` on it, so the content will be undefined.

Comment: My expectation is first to try the frame buffer without transformations to check that it works by defsult. I'm expecting that if I don't define any transformation in the frame buffer it will simply be a transparency over the image.

Comment: Then once that works I want to apply a transformation to invert the image. But for now my first expectation is just to read the image after it passes the framebuffer. If you are up for helping (you know I need it) assume I don't know anything about framebuffers. It is the truth

Comment: @RetoKoradi how do I actually render something with framebuffer?